# React only saves state to localstorage when I double execute the function why?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I want to save colors arrays in localstorage but when execute the `saveColors` function it just saves the former state, then I execute the `saveColors` again and it works. Why is this behaviour occuring and how to solve it?

[image]

Here's the example above 2nd save must have included the 5 objects inside the array. But instead when I click save again it saves it with 5 objects.

```
const [savedColors, setSavedColors] = React.useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('colors')) || [] );
      
      function saveColors(){
        setSavedColors(prevSavedColors => (
          [
            ...prevSavedColors,
            data.colors
          ]
        ))
        localStorage.setItem("colors", JSON.stringify(savedColors));
      }
```

For full code: http://pastie.org/p/2xYK30wTkqsb94ZU0Wk2C5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does calling react setState method not mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-does-calling-react-setstate-method-not-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: setState is async. State hasn't updated yet on the first call, but it is updated by the time you make the second call.

Comment: @JBallin What should I use instead of state hook? I didn't get how to fix it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState in react is async action therefore you didn't get what you wanted
You can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-does-calling-react-setstate-method-not-mutate-the-state-immediately) JBallin recommended to get reason for why it didn't immediately took effect

Here's how you can solve it

```js
const [savedColors, setSavedColors] = React.useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('colors')) || []);

function saveColors() {
  setSavedColors(prevSavedColors => {
    // instead of returning right away create a new array and save it in local storage
    const updatedColors = [...prevSavedColors, data.colors];

    localStorage.setItem('colors', JSON.stringify(savedColors));

    return updatedColors;
  });
}
```

Comment: `JSON.stringfy(updatedColors)` and it works thank you :)